Staging Ground redirecting to new question after review limit reached
When the review limit (50 new reviews on that day) on the Staging Ground is reached, the reviewer in question cannot review any new posts but further review actions can be taken on posts that the reviewer has reviewed before.
When taking such a review action after reaching the limit of 50 questions (and enjoying the beautiful modal) using another question that has been reviewed by the user before (e.g. when the author re-evaluated it), the reviewer gets redirected to another question to review. However, since the review limit is exceeded, there are no actions available.

Note that I am not talking about the last "first review action" that reaches the limit. I am talking about review actions after that. Also note that I don't think this bug is important in any way. Nevertheless, I think it should be documented.
expected behavior
The reviewer doesn't get redirected to a new question if the quota has been reached already. I would expect to be redirected to the questions page or the Staging Ground homepage or just stay on the reviewed question.
Actual behavior
The reviewer gets redirected to a new question that needs review but cannot be reviewed.

The redirection is already a bit questionable IMO. I don't like being queued. I like choosing a new review target for myself each time, even if it's that tiny bit slower.

You can do that by opening the questions in a new tab and just closing the tab after review. However, tbh opening questions manually isn't needed that much because (1) you don't need to be an SME to review questions (though it can be helpful) and (2) filters still apply for the automatic redirect.
